# Issue with expression trees - how to convert instance method to Func

Tags: c#, expression

I have a bit of code that currently uses reflection to invoke a method on a class, with the class and method names as strings. All methods on each class will have the same signature - taking string,string,IDictionary and returning bool.

What I'm trying to do is build this up with an expression and essentially cache the Func in a dictionary, so the reflection is only done the first time it's called. However I'm a bit confused on how to do this - I have the below code at the moment

```
public Func<string, string, IDictionary<string, string>, bool> GetFunc(string className, string methodName)
{
    lock (_locker)
    {
        if (!_criteriaCache.ContainsKey(className) || !_criteriaCache[className].ContainsKey(methodName))
        {
            object o = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance(className);
            var instance = Expression.Parameter(o.GetType(), "instance");
            var value = Expression.Parameter(typeof (string), "value");
            var compareValue = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "compareValue");
            var parameters = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IDictionary<string,string>), "parameters");

            var method = o.GetType().GetMethod(methodName,
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public);

            Func<string, string, IDictionary<string, string>, bool> result =
                Expression.Lambda<Func<string, string, IDictionary<string, string>, bool>>(
                    Expression.Call(instance,method,new List<Expression> { value,compareValue,parameters })).Compile();
            if (!_criteriaCache.ContainsKey(className))
                _criteriaCache.Add(className,new Dictionary<string, Func<string, string, IDictionary<string, string>, bool>>());

            _criteriaCache[className].Add(methodName,result);
        }
    }
    return _criteriaCache[className][methodName];
}
```

However I get an error on the Expression.Call function, saying 'Incorrect number of parameters supplied for lambda declaration'. What am I missing here?

Comment: Note that it is hard to be 100% sure of your intent here without a runnable example - I've taken a stab at it, but I can't verify anything

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide all your outer `ParameterExpression` declarations as the final parameter to `Expression.Lambda`. Currently you haven't given it any. However - it is unclear what you expect to do with `instance`, since your lambda *doesn't take* an instance. You might have meant `instance` to be `Expression.Constant(o)`:

```
var instance = Expression.Constant(o);
...
var result =
    Expression.Lambda<Func<string, string, IDictionary<string, string>, bool>>(
        Expression.Call(instance, method, new List<Expression> {
            value, compareValue, parameters }),
        value, compareValue, parameters).Compile();
```

---

It looks like you're doing a straight pass-thru of the parameters, though - in which case this might be simpler:

```
var result = (Func<string, string, IDictionary<string, string>, bool>)
      Delegate.CreateDelegate(
          typeof(Func<string, string, IDictionary<string, string>, bool>),
          o, method);
```

Comment: That is perfect - I didn't realise Expression.Constant had to be used for instances. Many thanks

Comment: @Chris see the edit: you might be over-complicating things

Comment: @Chris and `Expression.Constant` *doesn't have* to be used for instances - the point here is that it isn't a *parameter*, and needs to come from *somewhere* - `Expression.Constant` seems to represent your intent